# Shuffle array such that the expected index of an element will be its original index

Tags: python, random

Consider an array:

```
a=[0,1,2,3,4,5,6,...99]
```

I'd like to shuffle it so that each element is expected to end up in the position it started in; i.e. 0 is expected to end up in position 0, 1 is expected to end up in position 1, 2 is expected to end up in position 2.

I would also like to be able to use this for a general array.

---

edit:

I've made some progress, and i thought as the problem was generating some confusion, people might find this easier.

```
a = ['a','b','c']
b = list(range(0,len(a)))
c = np.random.normal(0,1,len(a))
d = b+c
np.sort(d)
```

The last line returns d sorted by d. I'd like to get the elements of `a`sorted by `d`. i.e. I'd like to get whatever map is applied to d in this sorting applied to `a`.

Comment: what have you tried so far pls post your code

Comment: I'm new enough to python that i can't make things quickly, but you well get the right shuffle by adding a second row that contains the index of each element, adding a normaly distrobuted random variable to every element in this row, then sorting by the second row, then removing it.

Comment: Can you elaborate on your question. what do you mean by "expected element"

Comment: ^ i've rewritten the question, to be more clear.

Comment: Y shuffle when you don't need to change position?

Comment: you could think of this shuffle as an an analogue of a martingale https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Martingale_(probability_theory)

Comment: does this answer your question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14755116/implement-a-classic-martingale-using-python-and-pandas

Comment: no - that looks unrelated

Comment: "I would also like to be able to use this for a general array" What do you mean by "general array" ? For example, do you mean a nested list with any depth of nesting? Or, a list with a mix of integers and floats?

Comment: I added  the code i have so far written to solve the problem, take a look and perhaps you can help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you're after [`numpy.argsort`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.argsort.html).  An implementation near to what you have would be something like:

```
import numpy as np

def nearsort(arr, *, amount=1):
    rv = np.random.normal(np.arange(len(arr)), amount)
    result = []
    for i in np.argsort(rv):
        result.append(arr[i])
    return result
```

the `amount` parameter determines the distance items can travel, smaller values makes large rearrangements less likely.  As a simple example, we get back `['b', 'a', 'c']` from:

```
np.random.seed(3)
nearsort(['a', 'b', 'c'])
```

Note that items can move arbitrarily far, so you might want to use a different distribution to get more control.  E.g., a uniform distribution (via `randint`) could be used, or maybe use `choice` with weights specified by `p` could be used for even more control.  For example:

```
def unisort(arr, *, pchange=0.1):
    weights = [pchange / 2, 1 - pchange, pchange / 2]
    rv = np.random.choice([-1.1, 0, 1.1], size=len(arr), p=weights)
    ii = np.argsort(np.arange(len(arr)) + rv)
    return [arr[i] for i in ii]
```

would ensure items don't move too far.

Comment: I'm new to python, why did you put a * in the second arg for your functions?

Comment: it forces following arguments to be [keyword only](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3102/)